# In App Purchasing in Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

i want to implement In app purchasing in my app. can you provide me a link or tutorial from which i can take help. i have no idea how it works.. thanks in advance...

Comment: I think you need to do some more research, look at possible solutions and then come here to ask for help with problems you ran against. Don't expect SO users to your research for you

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely consult the Corona Developer Portal. Chances are that if it's in the Corona SDK, it's documented there.

Android In-app Billing has been recently featured in their dev blog: [Getting Started with Android In-app Billing](http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2012/03/13/getting-started-with-android-in-app-billing/). For the Apple iTunes Store you may want to take a look at their reference for [Using In-App Purchases with the Apple iTunes Store](http://developer.coronalabs.com/reference/in-app-purchases). They do also have a section at their community forums specifically for In-App purchases which you may find useful.

You should probably take a look at the Stack Overflow guidelines too. By asking your question right, not only will you reduce the chances of having your question voted down or closed, but you'll also be more likely to get an useful answer right to the point.

Answer (score 0):

see there is a demo on inApp purchase by corona developer site,check this http://developer.coronalabs.com/sample-code/in-app-demo